# creating multiple thread with each data from a collection m

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

Here's the problem.

I'm trying to pass current variable value into a thread, is it possible without tricking it by create some text or objects?

In code it is something like this

```
List<Computer> students = new List<Computer>();

void main()
{
   for(int i=0; i<students.Count; i++)
   {
      Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Call(students[i])));
      thread.Start();
    }
 }

 void Call(Computer obj)
 {
    MessageBox.show(obj.Name);
    Doconnect(obj.ip);
 }
```

I'm trying to show every name with multiple thread so the application won't take along time to connect also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Since you're using a lambda, you need a local variable to avoid closure problems:

```
for(int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
{
    var student = students[i];
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Call(student))); // use local
    thread.Start();
}
```

That being said, it would be far better to just use the framework types, such as Parallel.ForEach:

```
Parallel.ForEach(students, s => Call(s));
```

Comment: What is this parallel does ?